# Music player that continuously play music even if no one is online

Tags: html, audio-streaming, jwplayer, playback

I was wondering if it's possible to have a music player that will always play music even that the user is not on the site.. Kinda like streaming... 
I am using jwPlayer but every time I enter the site my playlist starts from the beginning but I want her to keep playing even if I'm not there..
if there is anyway to do that please tell me..
Thanks in advance

Comment: Try not to demand something when asking a question. Also, questions work better when you show that you put some effort into it (showing relevant code really helps)

Answer (score 0):

You would need to have a virtual state that the server keeps track of. You would not really be streaming if you don't have a target device to stream to... so the server just needs to keep track of everything then continue streaming at the location you expect when the person reconnects to the server by whatever device they are using.

Comment: I don't want start exactly where I left.. I want it to keep playing and when I reconnect it's at the middle of another song.. Like a radio..
(thanks for the answer)